# ¿Por qué se usa "chuzar" en Colombia para designar "pinchar una comunicación"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, colombia

Leo en el periódico colombiano El Espectador:

> [Así ordenaron **chuzar** desde un esposo infiel hasta el fiscal general](https://www.elespectador.com/noticias/judicial/asi-ordenaron-chuzar-desde-un-esposo-infiel-hasta-el-fiscal-general-articulo-812375)

Una noticia que luego se desarrolla en estos términos:

> La imputación de cargos contra el general (r) Humberto Guatibonza, uno de los oficiales más emblemáticos de la Policía, y otras dos personas más reveló nuevos detalles de cómo supuestamente operó una red de **chuzadas** manejada por oficiales retirado con experiencia en inteligencia militar. La Fiscalía explicó paso a paso que una hacker radicada en Ipiales (Nariño) recibió órdenes del coronel (r) Jorge Humberto Salinas, el cerebro de la organización, para interceptar y violar la intimidad de cientos de colombianos. “Se ordenó **chuzar** desde a un esposo infiel hasta al fiscal general de la Nación”, fueron las palabras del fiscal del caso para resumir la investigación que comenzó a finales de diciembre de 2017.
>
> <sub>El Espectador, 15 septiembre 2018</sub>

Mirando en el DAMER vemos:

> [**chuzar(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chuzar).
>
> I.    1.  tr. Ni, Co, Ve, Bo; ES, rur. Pinchar o herir a alguien con un objeto cortante o punzante.
>   2.  intr. prnl. Ni, Pa, Co, Bo. Pincharse o herirse con un objeto cortante o punzante.
>   3.  tr. prnl. Co. Inyectarse droga. drog.
>
> II.   1.  tr. Co. Manipular una línea telefónica para espiar las conversaciones que se realicen a través de ella.

Por lo que parece que *chuzar* es sinónimo exacto de [*pinchar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T2baRVx), que en su 6.ª acepción se define como *Intervenir una línea o una comunicación telefónica*. Pero lo curioso es que este término solo se use en Colombia, así como que  en Colombia, Venezuela, Nicaragua, Bolivia y El Salvador sea sinónimo de pinchar. ¿Cómo se llegó hasta aquí? ¿Qué tan común es su uso?

Comment: @crows eso ya lo dije en la pregunta. Lo que resulta interesante es por qué se usa en Colombia y no en otros sitios

Comment: Curioso, por mi tierra "chuzarse" es "emborracharse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acerca del origen del término, hace unos años publicaron [este artículo](https://www.revistaarcadia.com/opinion/columnas/articulo/chuzar/21279), comentando que un chuzon (ya mencionado en el tesoro de Covarrubias) es un arma blanca larga (en pocas palabras) y desde el en el diccionario de la RAE en 1817 hasta hoy teniendo en cuenta la semejanza entre un [pincho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T2okNU7) (en su segunda acepción) y un [chuzo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=97YDR14) (en el diccionario actual), la sinonimia entre los verbos se justificaría.

La palabra ha tomado un uso casi cotidiano en Colombia desde hace unos 20 años, que se pone de moda la interceptación telefónica en el país (o al menos, que las personas afectadas lo empiezan a denunciar). No podría hablar de los demás países señalados